# Two gateways in the same VLAN

Tags: gateway

I have a server running on a network:
10.0.0.0/24

This Linux is running at ip address: 10.0.0.58

There are two good gateways in this network:
10.0.0.10 - That uses the provider number 1
and 10.0.0.11 - That uses the provider number 2.

I see other examples, but the gateways are using different VLANs. Not my case as you see.

How can I create those two default gateways and make the system to use the best gateway?

Comment: write a script which detects "the best" one.

Comment: I can write it, i was thinking if there is a better form. So i come here. Like using the ip route command.  To say something like if this router not working nice use the other one.

Comment: Time to use a routing protocol...as an added bonus if will provide an alternative path if the main path goes down. People tend to use OSPF, I prefer iBGP, more flexible and not dependent on multicast. Have a look at Quagga or BIRD

Comment: (I have used Quagga and iBGP for redundant routing, still use it today for anycast DNS)

Comment: Quagga dropped sysVinit god knows why, I would suggest going for BIRD.

Comment: sysvinit is still the best for our kind of job or for everyone, but i am starting to use systemD, horrible but necessary, for some reason everybody is dropping sysvinit. Is very likely that Linux Vista is comming up... I think the newest versions of ngnix and apache will come with a very simple If: If sysvinit is installed say a big error. And this can get worst... Maybe someday it will be on all BSDs, doing crazy daemon independant automatic start/stop/status service things nightmare.